# Gulp not adding correct css/js paths to index.html

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

Bootstrap loads correctly but not the custom `styles.css`

Notice the `'../public'` in Bootstrap and jQuery files, but not on `styles.css`

Here's `index.html`

```
<head>
  <!--bower:css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <!--endbower-->
  <!--bower:js-->
  <script src="../public/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../public/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <!--endbower-->
  <!-- inject:css -->   
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/styles.css">
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- inject:js -->
  <script src="/public/js/app.js"></script>
  <!-- endinject -->
</head>
```

Here's `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('inject', function () {
  var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
  var inject = require('gulp-inject');

  var injectSrc = gulp.src(
      ['./public/css/*.css', './public/js/*.js'],
      { read: false }
  );

  var options = {
      bowerJson: require('./bower.json'),
      directory: './public/lib'
  };

  return gulp.src('./views/*.html')
            .pipe(wiredep(options))
            .pipe(inject(injectSrc))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./views'));
});
```

Here's the error from accessing `index.html`

```
GET file:///C:/public/css/styles.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
GET file:///C:/public/js/app.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Project structure is

```
- project
    - public
        - css
        - js
        - lib
     - views
     gulpfile.js
     etc..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slash `/` before `public`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/styles.css">
<script src="/public/js/app.js"></script>
```

Should be removed, write this instead `="public/..` unless it will get path from the root of your drive if you are running locally.